# Get javascript function parameters

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I am trying to write a code for Greasemonkey. I can handle the tagnames, ids etc. But I got stuck in the 'script' tag. I can get the innerHTML of this script tag. But I want to get the input parameters only of the 'on' function, specifically 4th input which is a number. And store them in an array.

```
<ol id="online1">
        <script language="javascript" >
            on('0','2','abc','401757','');
    on('1','1','asd','1115337','');
    on('2','2','asdsad','1169333','');
    gi('asdasd','10453','');
    gi('asdasd','10453','');
.
.
.
.
</script>
```

Should result in

```
array = [401757,1115337,1169333];
```

I can get the innerHTML of the script like this:

```
window.frames[2].document.getElementById('online1').getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: If you got it as string, just parse it with regex.

Comment: Ok this is the first step. So you are saying that technically I can parse the contents between the 'on(' and ');' then parse the content between the 3rd and 4th comma.
Can you give a bit more clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your example, you can just use [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the innerHTML using `,` as a delimiter. If you want, you can add in an extra safeguard and use [a function to detect whether you're getting a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric).

JavaScript:

```
var vals = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[2].innerHTML.split(',');
for(var i = 3; i < vals.length; i+=4)
{
    console.log(vals[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
'401757'
'1115337'
'1169333'
'10453'
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zemhdngx/)

Comment: This makes sense too. Is this approach correct then?
1-split using ; to get rows
2-split using , to get parameters
3-check if the first parameter is 'on'

Comment: @ardavar Generally, that's the idea. Just keep in mind that if a comma or semicolon is missing this approach will fail.

Comment: This is close enough, in my example it will fail because parameters hence the commas are not standard in all functions I will add some checkpoints to filter the functions.